# comparing two strings in c

Tags: c

I have a basic question on strings and char array's in C.

below I have some basic code that compares data coming over a socket(telnet) with an existing string. This however fails. IF I compare a character in the char array it works in[1] == out[1].
Can you advise why the strings don't match and if I am missing something. Do I need to convert the char to anther type of string?

thx
Art

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
void dostuff(int); /* function prototype */
void error(const char *msg)
{
perror(msg);
exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, pid;
 socklen_t clilen;
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

 if (argc < 2) {
     fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
     exit(1);
 }
 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if (sockfd < 0)
    error("ERROR opening socket");
 bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
 portno = atoi(argv[1]);
 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
 if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
          sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
          error("ERROR on binding");
 listen(sockfd,5);
 clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
 while (1) {
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
           (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0)
         error("ERROR on accept");
     pid = fork();
     if (pid < 0)
         error("ERROR on fork");
     if (pid == 0)  {
         close(sockfd);
         dostuff(newsockfd);
         exit(0);
     }
     else close(newsockfd);
 } /* end of while */
 close(sockfd);
 return 0; /* we never get here */
 }

/******** DOSTUFF() *********************
 There is a separate instance of this function
for each connection.  It handles all communication
 once a connnection has been established.
*****************************************/
void dostuff (int sock)
{
int n;
char buffer[2];
char kjh[] = "aaa";

bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(sock,buffer,255);
if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
if (strcmp(ptr,kjh) == 0)
{ 
 printf("they are the same: %s.\n",buffer);
 do_other_stuff();
}
printf("Here is the message!: %s\n",buffer);
n = write(sock,"I got your message",19);
if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
}

void do_other_stuff()
{
printf("function works:");
}
```

Comment: -1: "Compiler error: `ptr` is not defined." Please post real, minimal, representative code.

Answer (score 1):

For a start the buffer is only 2 characters long, but the `read(sock, buffer, 255)` tries to read a lot more than that. In addition you need to add the null character at the end of the string before doing `strcmp`

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that can make this code to work is to have good basic knowledge, you are committing silly mistakes here, be observant and anticipate the areas where you probably will get lazy, like in pointers and string operations. Will help you in long run.